# How to Expand child nodes of tree list on click or dbl click on parent element?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

The issue is that when I click on tree list parent element it does not expand like it expand on DoubleClick in tree panel. anyone can help me to find what should I do to achieve that?In this image when I click on parent node it does not expands like we can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZgFa.png) but 
   it expands [on here in treepanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF3qV.png)

Comment: @gioalexiou can u please help me over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [Ext.list.Tree.expanderOnly](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.list.Tree.html#cfg-expanderOnly) to false to allow expansion on click of any part of the element.

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23nj).

Comment: yeah man you totally got my point that is exactly what i want <3